# Differential operator on linear functional

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ L:\mathbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ be the function $L(x)=\langle x|y\rangle$ , where $\langle|\rangle$ denotes some inner product on $\Bbb{R}^n$ and y is a fixed vector in $\Bbb{R}^n$. Further denote by DL, the derivative of $L$. Then which of the following are necessarily correct?

1. $ DL(u)= DL(v)$ for all $u, v \in \Bbb R^n$.
2. $DL(0,0,...,0)= L$.
3. $DL(1,1,...,1)= 0$.
4. $DL(x)=||x||^2,\forall x\in\Bbb R^n$.

By the definition of linear functionals. It seems $L$ is a linear functional.
$$L(x)=<x|y>=<(x_1,...,x_n)|(y_1,...,y_n)>=\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i$$

How to use $D$ in this problem?

I saw some answers in this app. But every answer choose correct options as incorrect options.

Correct answers are (1) and (2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $L$ is linear, so its derivative is constant and equal to itself. So indeed 1 and 2 are correct. Concretely, for any $x,h\in\mathbb R^n$
$$
\frac{|L(x+h)-Lx-DL(x)h|}{\|h\|}=\frac{|Lh-DL(x)h|}{\|h\|}.
$$
The only way this quotient can go to zero with $\|h\|$ is that $DL(x)=L$.

Comment: I have an doubt . This derivative formula is valid for $R^n\to R^m$.then how can you use here?

Comment: Take $m=1$. $ $

Answer (score 0):

For any linear operator $L:X\to Y$ the derivative is equal to $$D_xL=L$$ for all $x\in X.$

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: $$L(x+y)-L(y)  -L(x)=0$$ hence $$\frac{||L(x+y)-L(y)  -L(x)||}{||x||}=0$$